# Add Class to a div with PHP foreach

Tags: php

Consider this array of classes:

```
$array =['blue', 'gren', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'pink'];
```

I need for each each `div` to have a class:

```
foreach ($array as $div) {
    echo '<div class="">'.$div.'</div>';
}
```

Example of what I need:

```
<div class="first">blue</div>
<div class="second">gren</div>
<div class="last">red</div>

<div class="first">orange</div>
<div class="second">yellow</div>
<div class="last">pink</div>
```

Suppose I have 100 records in an array.

```
first
second
last

first
second
last

first
second
last

first
second
last

Etc.
```

Comment: and what is your problem? what have you tried?

Comment: how are the two arrays connected? (we only see the first one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $n => $div) {
    if ($n % 3 == 0) $pos = 'first';
    elseif ($n % 3 == 1) $pos = 'second';
    else $pos = 'last';

    echo '<div class="' . $pos . '">'.$div.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this should be achievable via the following code.
Consider tracking the current index (`$i`) of your iteration to determine the class to apply to a div. Notice I use the modulo operator `%` with a `switch` block to decide which class to use per iteration:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $div) {

    $i++;

    $class = "";
    switch ($i % 3) {
        case 0:
            $class = "first";
            break;
        case 1:
            $class = "second";
            break;
        case 2:
            $class = "third";
            break;
    }

    echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'.$div.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the array index to check if it's a `first`, `second` or `last` div, using the `%` operator. For example:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $div) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        $class = 'first';
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 1) {
        $class = 'second';
    } else {
        $class = 'last';
    }
    echo "<div class='$class'>$div</div>";
}
```